# Отфильтровать таблицу

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, обработка-данных

Как отфильтровать таблицу так, чтобы остались только по 3 дата с одинаковым значением, при этом важно, чтобы они были `state=person` и максимальное значение `price` или если нет ни одного `person`, то просто ориентироваться по максимальному `price`.

```
import pandas as pd
import xlrd

file = 'file.xlsx'

xl = pd.ExcelFile(file)

df1 = xl.parse('Лист1')

print(df1)
```

Входные данные:

```
   name  price   state  data
0  John   5678   robot     1
1  John    234  person     1
2  John    453   robot     2
3  John    789   robot     1
4  John   3213  person     2
5  John    848  person     1
6  John    993   robot     2
7  John     89  person     2
8  John    321   robot     1
```

На выходе ожидаю:

```
   name  price   state  data
5  John    848  person     1
1  John    234  person     1
0  John   5678   robot     1
4  John   3213  person     2
7  John     89  person     2
6  John    993   robot     2
```

Comment: А что вы сделали сами? Что именно у вас не получилось? Приведите код попытки. Открыть файл не считается за попытку.

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе небольшой, но воспроизводимый пример входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: @MaxU На вход идут данные с фото, которые сохранены в ексель, на выход должно быть так 
 John    848  person     1
 John    234  person     1
 John   5678   robot     1
John   3213  person     2
John     89  person     2
John    993   robot     2

Comment: `"на выход должно быть так ..."` - это пожалуйста в тело вопроса...

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VQ9t_hmOZqvvxgvPogo8Iw6UX5rZECyVVJZ5snp9cas/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

я бы делал это так:

```
res = (df
       .assign(x=np.where(df["state"].eq("person"), 1, 0))
       .groupby(["name", "data"])
       .apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(3, ["x", "price"]))
       .reset_index(level=[0,1], drop=True)
       .sort_values(["name","data","x","price"], ascending=[1,1,0,0])
       .drop(columns="x"))
```

результат:

```
In [56]: res
Out[56]: 
   name  price   state  data
5  John    848  person     1
1  John    234  person     1
0  John   5678   robot     1
4  John   3213  person     2
7  John     89  person     2
6  John    993   robot     2
```

Comment: Вы гений! Спасибо

Comment: А если я добавлю и data 3, то что поменять, чтобы отображалось под data 2